# The objects "TableName" and "TableName" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can someone explain what this error is?

The objects "TableName" and "TableName" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are making a join with the same table (TableName) you need to make different aliases for the SQL to know which column should he get from each table.